# Add results to a row regarding the last 12 months rows- SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

At my last meeting someone asked me if it was possible to hide people who where ill since a year from a dashboard. So I'm searching for the best way to actually KNOW who has been ill for 12 months.

I am working with a table with the number of days you've been absent for every kind of absence you could have, the number of days you should have been working that month, with a row per person, department and profession each month.

So it looks something like this :

| PersonID | YEAR | MONTH | DEPARTMENT | PROFESSION | Absence1 | Absence2 | Absence3 | WORKING DAYS OF THE MONTH... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 2021 | 07 | HR | ASSISTANT | 0 | 2 | 0 | 22 |
| 11111 | 2021 | 08 | HR | ASSISTANT | 0 | 0 | 0 | 22 |

==> So if I'm on a row of July 2021 I need to check the lines from June 2020 to June 2021.

My guess is that I need to add a column to this table who will say (with some kind of loop maybe) "if for the last 12 months (rows) the total number of days of absence equal the number of working days of the last 12 months then "ILL FOR A YEAR OR MORE" for each person (knowing that a person can work in more than one department or more than one profession so she'll have more than one row per month).

But I really have no idea how to actually write it in a script as I usually do very basic things. I'm using SQL SERVER and have 429 207 rows in the table. I'm thinking about doing it in the whole table and not only treating this month's rows because in the dashboard we show an historic.

Comment: What code do you have already for this dashboard?

Comment: I just use the table as it is and do the calculation in the dashboard's software. But I think if I had a column in the table recognizing the people absent for more than 12 months I could just hide all the rows with that term in the dashboard. I'm REALLY sorry if I'm not really clear, english is clearly not my first language.

Comment: I'm confused about what this table represents. Is it IllnessAbsence, if so does it have every month even if there is no absence, what does the number `2` signify, or is it just a table of Person (why are there duplicates then)

Comment: OK but at least you must know what this table means. We don;t even know its name or how it relates to any other tables in your database

Comment: I am so sorry, I thought it was clear the table is for all kind of absence. The numbers in the "illness" colums represent the number of days someone has been ill this month.

Comment: The name of the table is HETP_ABS, it as all the information about absences. I didn't speak about the other tables in the database because I don't think it's useful here (?), the only tables "related" to this one are dimensions table

Answer (score 0):

Your table is heavily denormalized. If you want to represent all this information in the database, I would have expected the following tables, instead of just one:

- Person
- Department
- Illness (list of illnesses)
- IllnessAbsence (join table between Person and Illness)

Either way, you can get the information you need with something like this:

- I've assumed you want the whole table, so you need a window function
- We need to flip the logic on its head: exclude all rows which have no *non-absence* in the last 12 months

```sql
SELECT
    PersonID,
    YEAR,
    MONTH,
    DEPARTMENT,
    PROFESSION,
    ILLNESS1,
    ILLNESS2,
    ILLNESS3,
    [WORKING DAYS OF THE MONTH]
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      NotIllLast12Months = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR + 1, MONTH, 1) >= GETDATE()
                  AND ILLNESS1 + ILLNESS2 + ILLNESS3 = 0 THEN 1 END)
        OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
    FROM HETP_ABS
) abs
WHERE NotIllLast12Months > 0;
```